# proof of existence

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration

While I was studying for my finals i found the following problem:

Let $f:[a,b]\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be a Riemann integrable real function, also let $\displaystyle \int\limits_a^bf(t)\,\mathrm{d}t=3$

Prove that there exist $\displaystyle t_1,t_2 \!\in \! (a,b):\int\limits_{t_1}^{t_2}f(t)\,\mathrm{d}t=1$

Could you give me any hint or a way to start the solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HINT: The function
$$
F(x)=\int_a^x f(t)\,dt 
$$
is continuous and $\int_a^a f(t)\,dt=0$.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:**

The function $F\colon [a,b]\to \mathbb{R}$ defined by $F(x) = \int_a^x f(t)dt$ is continuous, and $F(a)=0$, $F(b)=3$. Use the Intermediate Value Theorem on it.

Then:

> You can find $c\in(a,b)$ such that $F(c)=2$. Can you continue?

And then:

> Now, do a similar step with $G\colon [a,c]\to \mathbb{R}$ defined by $G(x) = \int_x^c f(t)dt$, to find $d\in(a,c)$ such that $G(d)=1$, i.e. $\int_d^c f(t)dt=1$.

Answer (score 0):

To be more careful, let $F(x) = \int_a^xf.$ Then $F$ is continuous on $[a,b]$ with $F(a) = 0, F(b) = 3.$ By the IVT, there exists $t_1\in (a,b)$ such that $F(t_1) = 1/2.$ Because $F$ is continuous on $[t_1,b]$ with $F(t_1) = 1/2, F(b) = 3,$ there is $t_2 \in (x_1,b)$ such that $F(t_2) = 3/2.$ It follows that $1 = F(t_2) - F(t_1) = \int_{t_1}^{t_2} f.$